# Special Character confilct in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch files and created a batch file to back up a networked drive at work to my OneDrive folder so that I could access work files at home.  Since then they have decided to install Office365 on everyones computer at work.  Now instead of OneDrives folder just being called 'OneDrive' it is now called 'OneDrive - G&S Foods, Inc'  My very simple batch file worked great until OneDrives name was changed. I cannot change the name back to just OneDrive, so I am trying to work around in my batch file.  It seems the special characters are giving me an issue though, expecially the &.  I now get the following error

> Invalid number of parameters '&' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

**My Question is:** What is the best way to work around the special characters issue?

**Here are my current script lines:**

```
@echo off
xcopy j:\Brandon C:\Users\bweibley\OneDrive - G&S Foods, Inc /m /e /y
xcopy J:\Joe's Folder\ChocScheduleBackUps C:\Users\bweibley\OneDrive - G&S Foods, Inc\ChocScheduleBackUps /m /e /y
```

Comment: Thats barely a programming related question. Use double quotes for every path/file name containing spaces or otherwise poisenous characters.

Comment: Best practice is to always enclose your file paths in double quotes regardless of needing them or not.  Then you never need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do so by enclosing the whole path in double quotes:

```
xcopy "j:\Brandon" "C:\Users\bweibley\OneDrive - G&S Foods, Inc" /m /e /y
```

You should already use double quotes if only a space is in there. So for your second line:

```
xcopy "J:\Joe's Folder\ChocScheduleBackUps" "C:\Users\bweibley\OneDrive - G&S Foods, Inc\ChocScheduleBackUps" /m /e /y
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
xcopy "j:\Brandon" "C:\Users\bweibley\OneDrive - G&S Foods, Inc" /m /e /y
xcopy "J:\Joe's Folder\ChocScheduleBackUps" "C:\Users\bweibley\OneDrive - G&S Foods, Inc\ChocScheduleBackUps" /m /e /y
```